# Adiabatic Invariance of 2 mass system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

I am trying to solve the second part of Problem 10 from [David Tongs CM notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics/mf4.pdf). Specifically we have

> The neutron star is in a non-circular orbit with $E < 0$. Give an expression for the adiabatic invariant $J(E, p_\theta, M)$ associated with the radial motion. The supergiant is steadily losing mass in a radiatively driven wind. Show that over a long time $E \sim M^2$.

My approach. $M(t)$ arises from the problem:

$$H = \frac{1}{2m}\left(p_r^2+\frac{p_\theta^2}{r^2}\right)-\frac{GM(t)m}{r}\implies p_r=\sqrt{2mE+\frac{2m^2GM(t)}{r}-\frac{p_\theta^2}{r^2}}$$
$$2\pi J=\oint p_r \, dr$$
So my question is where should I proceed from here?  I am not sure what my bounds should be on this.  If I look at the integral, it gets [nasty](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5BA%2BB%2Fr-C%2Fr%5E2%5D%2Cr%5D).  But then there is a hint with the integral in the text that doesn't make sense with regards to an $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Factorization

The first step is to write
\begin{align}
p_r
&=\sqrt{
2mE + \frac{2m^2 G M(t)}{r} - \frac{p^2_\theta}{r^2}
}\\
&=
\sqrt{
\frac{2mE r^2 + 2m^2 G M(t) \, r - p^2_\theta}{r^2}
}
\\
&=
\sqrt{
\frac{2mE(r-r_1)(r - r_2)}{r^2}
},
\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $r_1$ and $r_2$ (with $r_1 < r_2$) are two parameters to be determined.
Specifically,
\begin{align}
r_1 + r_2 &= -\frac{2 m^2 G M(t)}{2m E},
\tag{2}\\
r_1 r_2 &= -\frac{p^2_\theta}{2mE}
\tag{3}, \\
\end{align}
So two equations for two variables $r_1$ and $r_2$.
More explicitly, we can solve
\begin{align}
r_{1,2}
=
-\frac{m G M(t)}{2 E}
\pm
\sqrt{
\left(\frac{m G M(t)}{2 E}\right)^2
+\frac{p^2_\theta}{2mE}}.
\end{align}

### Doing the integral

Second, notice that $E$ is negative in a closed orbit, so Eq. (1)
can be written as
\begin{align}
p_r
&=
\sqrt{2m|E| \left(1-\frac{r_1}{r}\right)\left(\frac{r_2}{r} - 1\right) }.
\end{align}

Now we can use the formula provided in the note to do the integral
\begin{align}
\oint \sqrt{
\left(1 - \frac{r_1}{r}\right)
\left(\frac{r_2}{r} - 1\right)
}
dr 
&=2 \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \sqrt{
\left(1 - \frac{r_1}{r}\right)
\left(\frac{r_2}{r} - 1\right)
}
dr \\
&= 2 \, \pi \left( \frac{r_1 + r_2}{2} - \sqrt{r_1 \, r_2} \right).
\tag{4}
\end{align}
The factor “2” comes about
because $\oint$ means integration over a round trip, whereas $\int_{r_1}^{r_2}$ is only a half of it.  The bounds of $\oint$ are $r_1$ and $r_2$ because the round trip ends at $r_1$ and $r_2$, and the integrand becomes zero there (exceeding it would cause complex numbers, which doesn't make sense).

We can now do the integral
\begin{align}
2 \pi J
&=
\oint p_\theta \, dr
\tag{5}
\\
&=\sqrt{2 m E}
\oint \sqrt{
\left(1 - \frac{r_1}{r}\right)
\left(\frac{r_2}{r} - 1\right) } dr
\\
&=
\sqrt{2 m |E|} 2 \, \pi
\left( \frac{r_1 + r_2}{2}-\sqrt{r_1 \, r_2} \right)
\\
&=
\sqrt{2 m |E|} 2 \, \pi
\left( \frac{mGM(t)}{2|E|} - \frac{p_\theta}{\sqrt{2m|E|}} \right) \\
&=
2 \, \pi
\left( \frac{m^2GM(t)}{\sqrt{2 m |E|}} - p_\theta \right)
\end{align}
where we have used Eqs. (2) and (3) on the fourth line.

#### Why Mathematica failed

The problem that Mathematica didn't produce a nice result like this is because it tries to do an *indefinite* integral.  But for Eq. (5) we only need a *definite* integral, for which can take advantage of the fact that the integrand vanishes at the boundary to simplify the result.

### Adiabatic invariants

Now notice that $J$ and $p_\theta$ are adiabatic invariants, which means that if the parameter $M(t)$ is changed slowly, $J$ and $p_\theta$ are roughly the same.
This means that $\frac{ M(t) }{\sqrt{|E|}}$ should remain a constant, or
$$
E \sim M(t)^2,
$$
which is the desired result.